# Dataview, filter to see "All items"

Tags: data-view-web-part, filter

I have two dataviews in a page layout. The first one display all the categories of items, and then second one displays the items based on the selected category. It work find with filters and Query String, but I need to put an "All items" link.

Is there some way to display all items even if I use a filter like : "where category=*" or some kind of magic keyword?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same as above, but put your link into the DataviewWebPart somewhere instead of a separate CEWP, or set your AllItems link to just the FileDirRef value.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand the question is the filter is mandatory.  Without the ?Category filter, nothing will be displayed within the DVWP.  What James described may work, but I haven't tried it.  I do however know this technique works:
http://iturbandictionary.com/Susan/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=18

Give it a shot and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a few days ago. I ended up just creating a content editor web part and created a link back to the starting page. So it reloads it, getting rid of the filtering. Hope it helps.
-V