# Data View web part with text filter: show all list items by default?

Tags: 2010

I followed [these instructions](http://coolsharepoint.blogspot.be/2012/03/sharepoint-2010-configure-textfilter-to.html#!/2012/03/sharepoint-2010-configure-textfilter-to.html) and created a Web Part Page and filled it with a Text Filter Web Part and a SP Designer 2010 Data View. The result is I've not got a page where I can filter a list based on a wildcard text parameter. Great!

However, I cannot seem to get the list to display everything (unfiltered) by default. No parameter entered = no results returned apparently. How can I make it that, when a user opens the page and no parameters are entered, the entire list is shown?

My (so far unsuccesful) guess is that I need to add a second OR filter with a rule that's always valid (for instance, a required field that is not null - this is always the case obviously). But no luck so far. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please tell me how it got worked? I'm also facing the same issue.
PS: I'm not able to comment to the above, that's why added as a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out it might help you as its similar to your situation: [Dataview, filter to see "All items"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3876/dataview-filter-to-see-all-items)

This is for 2007 but should be similar:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/connect-a-filter-web-part-to-a-data-view-web-part-HA010250997.aspx